# HBITMAP to BITMAP converting

Tags: winapi, bitmap

Can't understnand what is wrong with this code:

```
HBITMAP bm = 0; 
BITMAP Bitmap;
bm = (HBITMAP)LoadImage (0, path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
int error = GetObject( &Bitmap, sizeof( BITMAP  ), &bm );
```

The LoadImage function returns non null pointer.
However GetObject returns 0, which indicates on error. 
I want to get size info and image data from HBITMAP pointer (the pointer can be passed as parameter, so I can't change the way I load the bitmap file).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe putting the parameters in the right places will help:

```
HBITMAP bm = 0; 
BITMAP Bitmap;
bm = (HBITMAP)LoadImage (0, path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
int error = GetObject( bm, sizeof( BITMAP ), &Bitmap ); // << NOTE ORDERING
```

See the documentation on [`GetObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more info.