# Send HBITMAP over socket

Tags: c++, sockets, bitmap

I need code in C++ that gets HBITMAP from one side and sends it through the socket and on the other side receive and make it HBITMAP again.

It has to be fast and effective

If it is more comfortable, use the GDI+ bitmap

Comment: Do you have code that saves an HBITMAP to a file?  If so, then take that code and just stream the bytes to the socket instead of to a file.

Comment: Well, do that first, that is, get code that saves an HBITMAP to a file. Then adjust the `fwrite`'s or whatever output function is being used to do `send` calls instead.  You will also need code that knows how to read a file and create the appropriate structures.  All of this is well documented, as this is basic bitmap handling in the Windows environment.

Comment: But how do I make it to HBITMAP after that again?

Comment: Please see my edit to the comment above. Basically what you're asking for is no different than saving and reading a bitmap file.

Comment: You should serialize to a stream. Use an image format that keeps the size down. For instance PNG might be appropriate. Then transmit that stream. At the other end de-serialze to an image. Pick an image library to do this with. `CImg` would be one obvious choice. GDI+, WIC would also work. There are oodles of such libraries. You might find that you already have one available.

Answer (score 1):

That's so not going to work!

What you need to go is convert the `HBITMAP` to a `BITMAP` using the [GetObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050919/hbitmap-to-bitmap-converting) function. Then serialize this object over the network. NOTE: You'll need to make sure you serialize the `bmBits` member correctly.

On the other side, once you've deserialized the `BITMAP` you can use [CreateBitmapIndirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a `HBITMAP`.

Comment: You've described the process for sending the bitmap *header* but not the bitmap *data*.

Comment: @MarkRansom - the bitmap data is the `bmBits` field in the `BITMAP` structure.

Comment: `bmBits` only contains the acutal bitmap data when the bitmap is a device independent bitmap. Otherwise you need to call `GetDIBits` to get the actual bitmap data.