# How do you get the value Gdiplus::Image::GetHorizontalResolution() returns via a HBITMAP?

Tags: winapi, gdi+, gdi

I've used `Gdiplus::Image::GetHorizontalResolution()` in printing calculations.  But now I'm wondering if I have just a HBITMAP in a generic print function, how do I get that same value `Gdiplus::Image::GetHorizontalResolution()` would return without having to setup a `Gdiplus::Image` object?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for this (GetObject) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050919/hbitmap-to-bitmap-converting

Comment: No, I was looking for the DPI.   It looks like the DIBSECTION does have one that can be calculated based on pixels per meter.   So if you can ensure HBITMAP is DIB then there is something to use.

Comment: I doubt that `HBITMAP`s store resolution information. While part of the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` it doesn't appear to be carried along. Unless you have access to the actual bitmap file, I doubt there's anything you could do to recover that information.

Comment: yeah, it was zero...

Comment: Maybe you want to get the `biXPelsPerMeter` in the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure by reading the bmp file: [Storing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/storing-an-image)